# mysql primary key violation when application running multiple nodes

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, spring-jdbc

I am developing an application using MySQL and spring jdbc , I am designing a table keeping in mind in future if have multiple instance of my application access a table to insert a record

Take this scenario.

```
 user
 --id
 --name
 --age
 --sex
```

I have three nodes running parallel

```
-------------------    -------------------    ------------------- 
|  node 1         |    |  node 2         |    |  node 3         |               
|  app instance 1 |    |  app instance 2 |    |  app instance 3 |          
-------------------    -------------------    -------------------
```

In such case, how to manage my primary key user.id when multiple nodes access at the same time

1. Will i face issue while using auto increment on primary key.
2. Can I handle through code, increment id and insert programatically, i see potential issue during concurrency, but right now i am following this approach.
3. Is there any other mechanism to handle concurrency issue on primary key generation.

What are the best practices in this regard.

EDIT:-  i am using spring jdbc batch insert, and i need to have the id generated through auto increment, but with jdbc batch this is not possible, hence i am manually incrementing the id and inserting.

Comment: When using `autoincrement` the database takes care of the PK instead of your application code. That's probably the safest and easiest way to go here.

Comment: @Mureinik i am using spring jdbc batch insert, and i need to have the id generated through auto increment, but with jdbc batch this is not possible, hence i am manually incrementing the id and inserting.